# Save multiple selection and retrieve selected using select2

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-select2, multipleselection

I have a profile edit form below in which I am asking the user to select multiple cities (I left 4, but on my page I am looking to add around 29,000) from a select2 dropdown menu using the following code, but the selected values do not save when I press the submit button and therefore when the page reloads there are no selected values.

```
  <form action="/edit-my-profile/?action=edit&#038;job_id=5792" method="post" id="submit-job-form" class="job-manager-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset class="fieldset-html">
                <label for="html">HTML</label>
                <div class="field ">
                    <select name='job_listing_region[]' id='regions' style='width:300px' multiple>
  <option>Boca Raton,FL</option>
  <option>New York City, NY</option>
  <option>Los Angeles, CA</option>
  <option>Boone, NC</option>
</select>               
</div>
</fieldset>
<p>
            <input type="hidden" name="job_manager_form" value="edit-job" />
            <input type="hidden" name="job_id" value="5792" />
            <input type="hidden" name="step" value="0" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit_job" class="button" value="Save changes" /> 
</p>
</form>
```

and the following jquery script

```
<script>

jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#regions").select2({
     });
});
    });

</script>
```

Is there a way I can have the selection box save the selected values?

Comment: hi Itamar, The id of the select in your HTML code is "regions" but in your jquery code, you are using "_regions".

Comment: Thanks. This is fixed, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Can you show the PHP code that saves the said files?

Comment: @Darren I am using a plugin that generates the form so I don't know how much help it may be, but I believe this the code that generates and submits the form.  http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/G05BuLF8Eh

Comment: Do you not have access to the code that saves the form? If not, do you know what kind of data/format it expects?

Comment: @Darren this is a template of the select field that the plugin generates, maybe it can help. http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/s5mddSjEXq